# Calculating Fourier transform of the function $f(x)= \frac{x}{x^2+a^2}$

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

How can one compute the Fourier transform in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ of the function $f(x)= \frac{x}{x^2+a^2} \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, where  $a$ is some positive real constant? The Fourier transform in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ is defined as $\hat{f}(t)= \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x) e^{- i t x }dx$ and Fourier transform for $ f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is defined as $$\hat{f}= l.i.m._{ n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-n}^{n}  f(x) e^{- i t x }dx$$

(It is limit in $L^2$-norm, as defined in book "Fourier and Wavelet Analysis"  from authors Bachman & Narici).

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Are you interested in other ways aside from the accepted solution?

Comment: @Mark Viola Yes, if there is another way, I would like to see it

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$f_a(x):={x\over x^2+a^2}={1\over 2i}\left [{1\over ix+a}+{1\over ix-a}\right ]$$
Observe that
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-at}e^{itx}\,dt=-{1\over ix-a},\quad \int_{-\infty}^0 e^{at}e^{itx}\,dt={1\over ix+a}$$
Let $$g_a(t)=-{1\over 2i}{\rm sgn}\,(t)e^{-a|t|}={i\over 2}{\rm sgn}\,(t)e^{-a|t|}$$
By the [Fourier inversion formula](https://candes.su.domains/teaching/math262/Lectures/Lecture02.pdf) we get
$$\widehat{f_a}(t)=2\pi g_a(t)=\pi i\,{\rm sgn}\,(t)e^{-a|t|}$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I just have to ask, when finding $L^2$ Fourier transform, is procedure same as in $L^1$? It seems that here it is the same, but I am confused about $l.i.m.$ part. What if I first tried to compute $\int_{-n}^n$, how then I find limit in $L^2$-norm? Could you please explain it?

Comment: It is hard to find the Fourier transform of the function $x/(x^2+a^2)$ directly. Since the function does not belong to $L^1$ you have to use the limit of proper integrals. Still it is hard to calculate those integrals explicitly. Perhaps some complex analysis methods can be applied. Instead I  have applied the trick  that it is not hard to represent the function as the inverse Fourier transform of a function $g_a$ which is absolutely integrable, even with exponential decay at $\pm \infty. $ Then the Fourier inversion formula completes the task.

Answer (score 1):

I thought it might be instructive to present two distinct approaches to find the Fourier transform of $\frac{x}{x^2+a^2}$.  To that end we now proceed.

**METHODOLOGY 1**: CONTOUR INTEGRATION

Let $f(x)=\frac{x}{x^2+a^a}$.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}\{f\}(k)&=\text{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{xe^{ikx}}{x^2+a^2}\,dx\\\\
&=2\pi i \begin{cases}
\text{Res}\left(\frac{ze^{ikz}}{z^2+a^2}, z=i|a|\right)&, k>0\\\\
-\text{Res}\left(\frac{ze^{ikz}}{z^2+a^2}, z=-i|a|\right)&, k<0
\end{cases}\\\\
&=i\pi \text{sgn}(k)e^{-|ka|}\tag1
\end{align}$$

---

---

**METHODOLOGY 2: DIFFERENTIAL EQUATION APPLICATION**

Let $g(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}$.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
G(k)&=\mathscr{F}\{g\}(k)\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ikx}}{x^2+a^2}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac1{|a|}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ik|a|x}}{x^2+1}\,dx\tag2
\end{align}$$

Owing to the uniform convergence of the integral of the differentiated integrand in $(2)$ for $k|a|$ bounded away from $0$ we have

$$\begin{align}
G'(k)&=i\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{xe^{ik|a|x}}{x^2+1}\,dx\\\\
&=i\left(\text{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ik|a|x}}{x}\,dx-\text{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ik|a|x}}{x(x^2+1)}\,dx\right)\\\\
&=-\pi\text{sgn}(k)-i\text{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ik|a|x}}{x(x^2+1)}\,dx\tag3
\end{align}$$

Note that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{xe^{ikx}}{x^2+a^2}\,dx=-iG'(k)$.

Next, for $k|a|$ bounded away from $0$ we differentiate $G'(k)$ (uniform convergence applies again) in $(3)$ to find that

$$G''(k)=a^2G(k)\tag4$$

Solving the ODE of $(4)$ yields $G(k)=A^+e^{k|a|}+B^+e^{-k|a|}$ for $k>0$ and $G(k)=A^-e^{k|a|}+B^-e^{-k|a|}$ for $k<0$.  Then, applying the initial conditions $G(0)=\frac\pi{|a|}$ and $G'(0^\pm)=\pm \pi$, we find that

$$G(k)=\frac{\pi}{|a|}e^{-{|ka|}}\tag5$$

Finally, differentiating $(5)$ and multiplying by $-i$ we find the coveted Fourier transform

$$\text{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{xe^{ikx}}{x^2+a^2}\,dx=i\pi \text{sgn}(k) e^{-|ka|}$$

which agrees with $(1)$.